# simple model when requesting collection and extended model when requesting resource - how

Tags: rest, architecture, restful-architecture

I have the following URI: `/articles/:id`, where article is a resource on web-service and have associated model/class. Now I need to return only partial data for each resource (to save bandwidth and make for speed) when collection is requested, but when a single item is requested from collection I need to send full data. My question is should I use two models/classes for the same resource on the server and initiate different one depending on collection or single resource is requested? Or maybe there is should be only one model/class but not all fields should be filled with data when a collection is requested? Or maybe there is another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the approach suggested [here](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#advanced-queries) with a `fields` query parameter.

If the API is going to be open to everyone to use and client usage is going to be unpredictable, then by default you probably need to limit the fields that you return. Just make sure you document in some way all the possible fields that could be used, in case a client actually needs them.

If the API is going to be consumed only by an app or apps you made, then by default you could return all of the fields and then your app can pass that `fields` parameter to speed things up.